# storing data for the session without using external database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I am creating a web application for a team based game. This is the scenario:

```
    1. First we enter the participants ID. After entering an ID 
       the user clicks save button and the same is displayed in a gridview below. 
       This way we enter multiple IDs and all of them are added in the gridview.

    2. Then we click shuffle and the inserted IDs are shuffled.
```

I already have the logic for the second part. But I am unable to store the IDs one after the other.
I want to know what is the best way to store the IDs for that session. I do not want to use any external DB. I have tried lists, arrays, dictionary, datatable etc but as soon as the user inserts an ID and clicks save, **the page reloads** and the new data over-rides the old one and only one ID is shown in the gridview. Can anyone suggest the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Store them in a session if persistence isn't required, if you wish the IDs to remain between sessions/users and not use a DB, then you can use a file (possibly a csv of IDs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Create `ArrayList` of ID and Save those In `Session`

**Save**

```
ArrayList Al=new ArrayList();

if(Al.Indexof("23"))         // check items already exists

Al.Add("12");                //adding items
Al.Add("13");
Al.Add("14");

Al.Remove("12")        //remove item

Session["myId"]=Al;
```

**Retrieve**

```
if(Session["myId"]!=null)
ArrayList Al=  (ArrayList) Session["myId"];
else
ArrayList Al=new ArrayList();
```

Comment: I was thinking of going with an external csv file. but your method looks great. Thanks

Comment: @nitinvertigo Using Collections you can easily manipulate it...Your welcome